# XPATH only return values for a specific row header, not all rows

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to use the name of a row heading that shows values underneath and want to return only the values under the header I name. I am trying this:

```
 //div[@class='rowh'][contains(., 'Body Glass')]/following-sibling::div
```

But it returns ALL values on the page. The only values I want are:

```
Heated Rear Window
Tinted Windows
```

But I cannot seem to limit the xpath to only this. It picks up everything:

```
Heated Rear Window 
Tinted Windows 
Brakes
Anti-lock Braking System - ABS and Emergency Brake Assist - EBA 
ESC - Electronic Stability Control with ASR - Traction Control and Hill Start Assist - HSA 
Communication
Pre-Wiring for Accessory Fit Radio and Speaker System 
Doors
Black Door Mirrors 
Door Mirrors - Manually Adjustable 
Manual Windows - Front 
Manual Windows - Rear 
Driver Aids
```

I have tried adding [1] to the xpath and various other stuff but cannot seem to work this out. HTML code below:

```
<div class="vdatatable">


<div class="rowh">Body Glass</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Heated Rear Window</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Tinted Windows</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Brakes</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Anti-lock Braking System - ABS and Emergency Brake Assist - EBA</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">ESC - Electronic Stability Control with ASR - Traction Control and Hill Start Assist - HSA</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Communication</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Pre-Wiring for Accessory Fit Radio and Speaker System</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Doors</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Black Door Mirrors</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Door Mirrors - Manually Adjustable</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Manual Windows - Front</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Manual Windows - Rear</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Driver Aids</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">3-Point Rear Seatbelts x3</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Airbags - Driver</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Airbags - Front Passenger with Deactivation Function</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Airbags - Front Side</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Child Locks in Rear Doors</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">ISOFIX Points for Child Seats in Outer Rear Seats</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Seatbelt not Fastened - Visual and Audible Warning</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Thatcham Approved Engine Immobiliser</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Driver Convenience</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">12V Power Socket by Gear Lever</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Driver Information</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Door Open - Visual Warning</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Gear Shift Indicator</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Rev Counter</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Tyre Pressure Monitor</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Engine</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Power Assisted Steering</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Exterior Body Features</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Bumpers - Front and Rear in Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Chrome Front Grille Strip</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Door Handles - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Fog Lamp Embellisher - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Exterior Lights</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Headlights - Double Optic with Chrome Surrounds</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Headlights Left On - Audible and Visual Warning</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">High Level Third Brake Light</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">LED Daytime Running Lights - DRL</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Interior Features</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">3-Speed Front Windscreen Wipers</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Air Recirculation - 4-speed Heating and Ventilation</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Air Vents Surrounds - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Central Console Surround - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Door Handles - Interior Front - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Door Handles - Interior Rear - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Door Panels - Two-Tone Dark Carbon-Light Grey</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Height-Adjustable Front Headrests</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Instrument Dial Surrounds - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Rear Wash-Wipe</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Interior Lights</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Front Courtesy Light</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Paintwork</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Paint - Solid - Glacier White</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Seats</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Seats - 60-40 Split Folding Rear</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Trim</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Upholstery - Cerite Cloth - Black</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>


<div class="rowh">Wheels</div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row" data-oid="0"><div class="key">15in Steel Wheels - Tarkine Wheel Trims</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
<a name="anc0" class=""></a><div class="optexrow oid0 row1" data-oid="0"><div class="key">Tyre Inflation Kit</div><div class="value"> </div><div class="cf"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have two suspected culprits. Consider: //div[@class='rowh']/.[contains(., 'Body Glass')]/following-sibling::div the other is something around the contains function

Comment: You have a structural problem with the HTML you provided, you mention "row heading that shows values underneath", but they're not underneath as they're all siblings, that's why you're getting those results. Do you have the ability to change the HTML?

Comment: No, cannot change the html. If my description of what's going on there is incorrect, then that's my fault.

Comment: @StephenFlynn - this xpath seems to be invalid

Comment: Try: //div[@class='rowh']/.[contains(text(), 'Body Glass')]/following-sibling::div

Comment: The difference is the text() node

Comment: If its always need to take 1st and 2nd then you can use `//div[@class='rowh'][contains(., 'Body Glass')]/(following-sibling::div[1]|following-sibling::div[2])'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option that selects the two `div` elements...

```xml
//div[contains(preceding-sibling::div[@class='rowh'][1],'Body Glass')]/div[@class='key']
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks so much.